# rails association populate field from another table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

Hoping this will be a straight forward question, but is anyone able to let me know the best way of populating a hidden field based on a value on another table.

I currently have 2 tables - `table_numbers` which has the following fields - id and value(decimal), and `table_records` which has an amount field.

On the form to add a new record I have the following to add a value to it

```
= f.association :table_number, :collection => table_numbers.order('value ASC'), :label_method => :value, :prompt => "Select a value", :label => "value"
```

At the moment this is populating the number_id on the records table, but displaying the value on the form when adding a record.  What I would like is to get the value as well to be able to run a calculation on the value and amount.

What would be the best way to do this?  Update the line above or do I need to add extra code?

Thanks

Comment: Will you need the value for calculations after the form is submitted? Since you have the id of the table_number record, you can get the value from it.

Comment: Once the calculation has been made then no, the value will be displayed but thats not an issue at the moment.  Thanks

Comment: Do you still have a question? If so can you clarify it as its not clear what you are trying to do?

Comment: Apologies that last comment doesn't make much sense.

Comment: When the calculation is made, and the record is saved then the calculation needs to stay in place for further new records.  I think the easiest way to look at it is 2 tables - products and orders, on the products you have the id and product cost while on the order you have the quantity.  what I am try to do is multiply the product cost and the quantity but at the moment I am only getting the id not the cost value to calculate.  Hope this makes more sense.

Answer (score 0):

You can perfom calucaltions in before_save callback in model. If you want to display calculations, use helper and show it.